# Get "additional include paths" from other project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, simulink

I have a codebase in C#.
I also have a project in C - which is autogenerated by Simulink Coder. I wish to create an interface between these two projects. The C project does not expose everything I want to access, and since it is autogenerated I do not want to touch it, since these changes will be lost the next time I generate a new project.

The solution I am trying to get working is to create an intermediate project in C/C++ which references the project in C (from Simulink). By adding the C projects as a reference I have access to more or less everything, and I can expose whatever I want to C#.

This is all fine. However, in order for this to work my C++ needs to have the same include paths as the C project - and these paths are generated by MATLAB/Simulink and will vary form computer to computer.

Is there an easy way to make my C++ project just inherit the include paths from the C project. My goal is to just have a static solution in Visual studio where I can update my autogenerated project from Simulink and access it from C# without having to modify a lot of build settings first.

Comment: If you want to invest the effort, you could probably accomplish this using creative use of property sheets - see [Working with Project Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx).

Comment: @PhilBrubaker I'm not sure I can. You can make a property which applies to both project A and project B. But I don't think you can make a property which takes a value from project A and applies it to project B

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of something that, perhaps in the Intermediate project you suggest, using a Build Event that queries the directory settings from the C project and populates a property sheet that could be imported by the dependent project.

Comment: @PhilBrubaker A Pre-build event could perhaps work. I'll take a look at it